# ggplot2 reordering special variable ..count

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi suppose I have this plot here.

```
Fruit <- c(rep("Apple",3),rep("Orange",25), rep("Peach",5)   )


df <- data.frame(Fruit)

ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Fruit), position = "dodge")
```

this code will produce 
[image]

however what I really want is to sort by descending order so that orange will be first follow by peach.  I could produce a frequency table and create a factor with level sorted but I'm wondering if there is anyway to do this within the special variable itself.

thanks!

Comment: Try this `ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Fruit), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = names(sort(table(Fruit), decreasing = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `forcats` package and reordering the factor levels first according to their frequency. Then your plotting code can remain the same and you should get what you want.

```
library(forcats)
df$Fruit <- fct_infreq(df$Fruit)

ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, ..count..)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Fruit), position = "dodge")
```

[image]